# Is there any way in laravel to get the latest records against multiple shipment_ids

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need the all the updated rows from the following data, I have a repetition of shipment id in my table from this I only need updated rows of each shipment id.

In my table there are multiple shipment ids and all are repetitional like:

```
id    date         shipment_id
1  2020-09-09        12
2  2020-10-05        12
3  2020-10-23        12
4  2020-09-09        13
5  2020-10-05        13
6  2020-10-23        13
```

Output should be:

```
id    date         shipment_id
3  2020-10-23        12
6  2020-10-23        13
```

I need the latest record of every shipment_id

[its the original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJRfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way (Group by with max value query)

```
   $data = Shipments::select('id', 'shipment_id', DB::raw('MAX(date) as latest_date'))
                            ->where('is_active', 1)
                            ->groupBy('shipment_id')
                            ->get();
   
    dd($data);
```

Ref : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-group-by-with-max-value-query-exampleexample.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into querying via the Eloquent ORM.

The query should look something like this:

```
Shipments::orderBy('id', 'desc') ->groupBy('shipment_id') ->get();
```

To speed up the query we can leverage your id(increment_id) hence the largest id, with a certain shipement_id, always will be the newest.